# Scala Doobie PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at end of input when use "Like %"

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, doobie

I am using PostgreSQL 12.1 with Scala and Doobie. Getting exception when trying to do query with LIKE % syntax. It works without %.

My code:

```
implicit val cs = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContexts.synchronous)

val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
val connectionString = "jdbc:postgresql:postgres"
val user = "postgres"
val pass = "P@ssw0rd"

lazy val xa = Transactor.fromDriverManager[IO](driver, connectionString, user, pass)

def findNamePref(title: String): Option[Book] = {
    val s = sql"SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE $title%".query[Book].option
    s.transact(xa).unsafeRunSync()
}
```

Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   syntax error at end of input   Position: 41   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2505)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2241)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368)    at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108)
>     at
>   doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter$PreparedStatementInterpreter.$anonfun$executeQuery$2(kleisliinterpreter.scala:956)
>     at
>   doobie.free.KleisliInterpreter.$anonfun$primitive$2(kleisliinterpreter.scala:112)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:87)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.startCancelable(IORunLoop.scala:41)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.run(IOBracket.scala:86)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.cats$effect$internals$Trampoline$$immediateLoop(Trampoline.scala:70)
>     at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.startLoop(Trampoline.scala:36)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.super$startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.$anonfun$startLoop$1(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
>     at
>   scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)
>     at
>   scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC$JVMTrampoline.startLoop(TrampolineEC.scala:93)
>     at cats.effect.internals.Trampoline.execute(Trampoline.scala:43)    at
>   cats.effect.internals.TrampolineEC.execute(TrampolineEC.scala:44)     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:72)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IOBracket$BracketStart.apply(IOBracket.scala:52)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$.cats$effect$internals$IORunLoop$$loop(IORunLoop.scala:136)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.signal(IORunLoop.scala:355)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:376)
>     at
>   cats.effect.internals.IORunLoop$RestartCallback.apply(IORunLoop.scala:316)
>     at cats.effect.internals.IOShift$Tick.run(IOShift.scala:36)     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Dependencies:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"


lazy val doobieVersion = "0.8.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-core"     % doobieVersion,
  "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-postgres" % doobieVersion,
  "org.tpolecat" %% "doobie-specs2"   % doobieVersion
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will replace the content of `$title` with the value from the function parameter.

The query however contains a `%` after the parameter. Once replaced with a value, the SQL would look like `... WHERE title LIKE 'myTitle'%`, which is invalid.

You can concatenate the `%` to the given parameter

```
val s = sql"SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE $title || '%'".query[Book].option
```

which would translate to `... WHERE title LIKE 'myTitle' || '%'` then to `... WHERE title LIKE 'myTitle%'`

Answer (score 1):

The **why** described already *JGH*.

A simple fix would be to add `%` to the parameter.

Request:

```
val s = sql"SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE $title".query[Book].option
```

Examples:

```
findNamePref("Title")
findNamePref("Tit%")
findNamePref("%itle")
findNamePref("%")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got this error is you inscribed a string variable in a string itself i.e. title in your case. On usage, the string variables gets substituted to its value hence inscribing a string value within double quotes is again a syntax error. So,
you should use title explicitely by concatenation of the title value to the select query string.

```
    "select * from.... Where title like %" 
   +title+"%" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. This is what i use after all:

```
sql"SELECT * FROM books WHERE title LIKE ${title+"%"}".query[Book].option
```